# Django : How to ensure a unique value for a field or group of fields in a record / form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm using a ModelForm and i'm happy with the default validation and errors.
In my template i use a simple:
`{{ form.as_ul }}` with a `{% if form.errors %}` block.

The Model contains among other things those fields :

```
group1_wish1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=GROUP1CHOICES)
group1_wish2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=GROUP1CHOICES)
group2_wish1 ....
group2_wish2 ....
```

Each user is not allowed to make the same wish twice for each group : group_wish1 != group_wish2.

Is there a validation option for models that would let me achieve this ?

I've looked at `unique` but it works at the table level.

Any idea how i could it as simply as possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way should be overriding the form's clean()-method in the definition of your ModelForm (forms.py).

See the Django documentation:
[Cleaning and validating fields that depend on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)
[ModelForms: Overriding the clean()-method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method)

Comment: Thanks ! Works like a charm and it was easier than i thought :
`class MyModifiedModelForm(MyModelForm):
 def clean(self):
  cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
  g1w1 = cleaned_data.get('group1_wish1')
  g1w2 = cleaned_data.get('group1_wish2')
  if g1w1 == g1w2:
   raise forms.ValidationError('Wish 1 and 2 must be diffrent')`